# enum with multiple values

Tags: c#, enums

In my model I have this code

```
public enum StockStatus
{       
    Origin= 1,

    [Display(Name = "In Transit")]
    InTransit = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Port Louis")]
    PortLouis = 6,
    Yard = 7,
    Requested = 8
}
```

I need to be able to have multiple values for Origin something like this

```
public enum StockStatus
{       
    Origin= 1,2,3,4,        

    [Display(Name = "In Transit")]
    InTransit = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Port Louis")]
    PortLouis = 6,
    Yard = 7,
    Requested = 8
}
```

i know it is not ok but i need to be able to do it this way

Comment: You can use [Flags] attribute

Comment: you can use `class` instead of `enum`, I wonder why you want to do that with `enums`?

Comment: "Consider" enum as an integer - you are saying "can I save 1,2,3,4 into 1?"

Answer (score 6):

You need to have the enum as Flags and the value needs to be bitwise unique(power of 2).

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{

    Origin= no1 | no2 | no3 | no4,

    no1 = 1,
    no2 = 1 << 1,
    no3 = 1 << 2,
    no4 = 1 << 3,

    [Display(Name = "In Transit")]
    InTransit = 1 << 4,
    [Display(Name = "Port Louis")]
    PortLouis = 1 << 5,
    Yard = 1 << 6,
    Requested = 1 << 7
}
```

Comment: could you post a use case? how do you choose `no2` as `Origin`? MyEnum enumValue = MyEnum.???

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is not displaying origin but it is displaying no1,no2,no3,no4 instead of Origin.

Comment: @Nasif perhaps put `[Display(Name= "Origin")]` attribute for all `no1~4`?

Comment: @MongZhu To be honest, I am not sure with your question, but your question's answer is simply `MyEnum.no2` which is a member of `MyEnum.Origin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have comma separated values with enums.

You can do something like this:

```
public class StockStatus
{       
    public List<int> Origin= new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};

    [Display(Name = "In Transit")]
    public List<int> InTransit = new List<int>(){ 5};
    [Display(Name = "Port Louis")]
    public List<int> PortLouis = new List<int>(){ 6};
    public List<int> Yard = new List<int>(){ 7};
    public List<int> Requested = new List<int>(){ 8};
}
```

this way you will be able to have multiple values for Origin

Answer (score 1):

The [Flags] attribute on an enum allows you to assign multiple values to your enum at once. You can do this with bitwise manipulations

```
[Flags]
public enum StockStatus
{
    Origin = 0x0 | 0x1 | 0x2,

    [Display(Name = "In Transit")]
    InTransit = 0x4,
    [Display(Name = "Port Louis")]
    PortLouis = 0x8,
    Yard = 0x10,
    Requested = 0x20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this:

```
class Status
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int code = 1;
        string name;
        Dictionary<int, string> StatusMap = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 1, "ORIGIN" },
            { 2, "ORIGIN" },
            { 3, "ORIGIN" },
            { 4, "IN TRANSIT" }
        };

   if (!StatusMap.TryGetValue(code, out name))
   {
       Console.WriteLine(name);
       // Error handling here
   }
  }
}

// or a method like this
public static string GetStatus(int code)
{
    string name;
    if (!StatusMap.TryGetValue(code, out name)
    {
        // Error handling here
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible, because following will be ambiguity.

```
StockStatus aStatus = StockStatus.Origin;
```

if am i, i will define Origin and OriginMax.

```
Origin= 1,
OriginMax= 4,
```

*Usage:*

```
1. StockStatus aStatus = StockStatus.Origin;
2. if (aStatus >= StockStatus.Origin && aStatus <= StockStatus.OriginMax)
```